# Unable to login on my jhipster 4 project with uaa, a microservice and a gateway and running with consul

Tags: jhipster, microservices

I've generated a jhipster 4 project with uaa, a microservice and a gateway and running with consul. All start well but i'm unable to login

Error:

Filter: Access Control: allowing access for /uaa/api/account, as no access control policy has been set up for service: uaa

Error during filtering
/uaa/api/account [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
    ...
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Here .yo-rc.json file for uaa server

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
      "nativeLanguage": "fr"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.3.0",
    "baseName": "uaa",
    "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
    "packageFolder": "com/mycompany/myapp",
    "serverPort": "9999",
    "authenticationType": "uaa",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "consul",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "applicationType": "uaa",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "skipClient": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "fr",
    "languages": [
      "fr"
    ],
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn"
  }
}
```

Here .yo-rc.json file for my microservice

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
      "nativeLanguage": "fr"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.3.0",
    "baseName": "resource",
    "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
    "packageFolder": "com/mycompany/myapp",
    "serverPort": "8081",
    "authenticationType": "uaa",
    "uaaBaseName": "uaa",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "consul",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "1eada7e399535cfc724344c47d3dae65e47455a1",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "applicationType": "microservice",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "skipClient": true,
    "skipUserManagement": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "fr",
    "languages": [
      "fr",
      "en"
    ],
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn"
  }
}
```

Here .yo-rc.json file for my gateway

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
      "nativeLanguage": "fr"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.3.0",
    "baseName": "gateway",
    "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
    "packageFolder": "com/mycompany/myapp",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "uaa",
    "uaaBaseName": "uaa",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "consul",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "clientFramework": "angular2",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "gateway",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber",
      "protractor"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "fr",
    "languages": [
      "fr",
      "en"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you see all your apps in consul?

Comment: Yes, i can see :consul  <passing>
gateway  failing
resource failing
uaa failing

Comment: At http://localhost:8500, all the services (consul, uaa, resource, gateway) are shown but only consul has status passing.

Comment: it is working now, i've emptied the browser s cache and restart all. Thank u.

Comment: Do you have solution ? I have the same problem